# Probability to detect

Tags: probability

The probabilit that a radar will detect an object in one cycle is p .Then what is The probability that the object will be detected in n cycles .

I think it should be $ p^n$

but the answer is given as $1-(1-p)^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming independence of detection in each cycle:

- $p^n$ is the probability of detection in all $n$ cycles
- $(1-p)^n$ is the probability of no detection in any of the $n$ cycles
- $1-(1-p)^n$ is the probability of detection in at least one of the $n$ cycles

Answer (score 1):

First, a little thought will tell you that $p^n$ can't be right, since that decreases as $n$ increases while the probability of detection increases with each attempt.

The best way to think about this is to calculate the probability that you fail to detect it. That's $(1-p)$ for each cycle, so the probability that you fail to detect it in $n$ cycles is $(1-p)^n$. That probability of failure increases, as it should. The complement, $1 - (1-p)^n$, is the probability that you find it. That increases to $1$ as $n$ grows.